# Create PDF Annotations Using PDFKIt iOS 11

Tags: swift, annotations, ios11, pdfkit

I'm actually trying to draw ink/freedraw annotation using PDFKit annotations on pdf but not able to draw the annotation.

In ink annotation provided by apple, there is a method to add Bezier path to the annotation.

```
// Add or remove paths from the annotation.
// Path points are specified in annotation space.
// Used by annotations type(s): /Ink.
open func add(_ path: UIBezierPath)
```

Even when the path is added, annotation is not drawn on PDF.
Thank you in advance for all the precious answers.

Comment: is it possible to help me? I am working on pdf kit and I need to run editor to create pdf. If you have any information and if possible please uodate your code or help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609287/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-image-which-taken-by-camera-with-pdfkit

Comment: Hello @nedaDerakhshesh actually  we were doing POC on PDFKit and due to unavailability of proper documentation we stopped working on that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have a problem with `UIBezierPath` or `PDFAnnotation`, but here is a working example.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!

func addInkAnnotation() {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 100.0, height: 20.0)
    let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: rect, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
    annotation.backgroundColor = .blue

    let pathRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: pathRect)
    annotation.add(path)

    // Add annotation to the first page
    pdfView.document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: Rebacz I was trying to execute this but no working, can you elaborate

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad(); pdfView.document = pdfFile; addInkAnnotation() }`
and this is it.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how you creat the outlet for pdfView with PDFView properties, because with my method I assign pdfView as subview on run document is not annotating / not sensing the touch of pen

Comment: To create outlet: 1. Add a subview in interface builder. 2. Change its class (custom class) to PDFView, as in: https://ibb.co/bCOGV6 3. Create outlet in your view controller. This is it ;)

Comment: @RafałRębacz I would really appreciate if you have any information about how to run and save an editor with ios pdfkit let me know. thank you very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609287/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-image-which-taken-by-camera-with-pdfkit