# how to create a pdf from image which taken by camera with pdfkit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, pdfkit

Hi I am new to `pdfkit` and iOS applications, I want to take a picture with device and then convert the image to pdf. taking pictures with camera and saving it on Camera Roll works completely fine, the problem is when I want to create pdf from that image it needs the name of the image, how I can find it? 
and another question is it possible to implement any pdf editor with `pdfkit` to edit image?
Appreciate any help. below is my `imagePickerController` codes.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    if (Mylibrary)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage!, nil, nil, nil);
        let image = UIImage(named: "????") //the problem is here
        let newPage = PDFPage(image: image!)
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)




}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to instantiate a new image since the image is already stored in the `pickedImage` variable. You just need to initialize the new  `PDFPage` object with `pickedImage`. Use `ImageKit` to edit the image before using it to initialize a new `PDFPage` object.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }

    // Adds pickedImage to the user’s Camera Roll album.
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, nil, nil, nil)
    // Creates a new PDFPage object and initializes it with pickedImage.
    let newPage = PDFPage(image: pickedImage)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that image kit is the one which I need? I need a editor for users who can edit images with text and so on, does pdfkit have this ability or should I implemen an extra editor for it?

Comment: and also what is newPage url? and how I can save that newPage in NS file manager? should I ask another question? let me know. thank you so much.